# Upstart job and dependencies

Tags: upstart

We have three jobs, job1, job2 and job3. With job3 depending on the other two:

**job3 config**

```
start on (started job1 and started job2)
stop on (stopping job1 or stopping job2)
```

with this configuration, job3 starts on OS start up. And in the event of failure of one of the other two, say job1, job3 will stop; but if job1 recovers from it's failure, job3 will not be started, because [upstart has events, not states](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#events-not-states).

One possible workaround will be to check the status of job2 in post-start script of job1, and if it is running, emitting an event to trigger the start of job3, with the same logic for job2:

**job1 config**

```
post-start script
  if job2 is running emit event
end
```

**job2 config**

```
post-start script
  if job1 is running emit event
end
```

**job3 config**

```
start on event
```

This obviously is not a clean solution and needs more changing when more jobs are created etc.
Is there any better way of doing this?